# Is there a mathematic expression for this sequence

Tags: sequences-and-series, algorithms

I want to arrange a sequence from $1$ to $n$, so that every time I

(i) remove 1 number and add it to the list;

(ii) move the next number to the bottom of the sequence.

finally I can get a sequence of $1$ to $n$.

For example:

```
1,4,2,6,3,5 -> 2,6,3,5,4 -> 3,5,4,6 -> 4,6,5 -> 5,6 -> 6           
               (1)          (1,2)     (1,2,3)   (1,2,3,4)  ...
```

Is there a mathematic expression for the initial arrangement? (i.e number $i$ is put at position $f(i)$ )

Comment: Not sure what your question is. Are you asking if this is a sorting algorithm?

Comment: OP is looking for a simple formula that generates the proper permutation.

Comment: @k170 That's what I'm asking for.... given the final sequence 1,2,3,...n

Comment: @k170 it is 1,6,2,10,3,7,4,9,5,8

Comment: Is this the "Australian shuffle" (aka the "down and under shuffle")? That is, you put the first card _down_ on the table, the next card _under_ the deck, the third card _down_ on the table, the fourth _under_ the deck, etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would start by considering the numbers from $0$ to $n-1$ and let $n=2^k$.  The correct order then is $0,4,1,6,2,5,3,7$ Let the function be $f(i,k)$ is the position to put $i$ in when the list is $2^k$ long.  To generate the correct sequence of length $2^{k+1}$, you add $2^k$ to each of these numbers and shuffle in the small ones, getting $0,8,1,12,2,9,3,14,4,10,5,13,6,11,7,15$  The formula becomes $$f(i,k)=\begin {cases} 2i & i\lt 2^{k-1}\\2f(i-2^{k-1},k-1)+1& i \ge 2^{k-1} \end {cases}$$ A similar formula works for strings that are not a power of $2$, but you have to worry about what happens for an odd length.  This is remeniscent of the [Josephus problem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Josephus_problem).  The rule for $i \ge 2^{k-1}$ becomes:  let there be $m\ 1$'s before the first zero.  Then $f(i,k)=(2^m-1)+2^{k-m+1} ($rest of number after the first zero$)$.  For example $f(13,4)=3+8(1)=11$